# Sliding window in python changes shape

Tags: python, image, loops, numpy

I'm using the following function to slide over a larger image and pull windows of (64, 64, 3) for classification from a CNN.

```
def find_vehicles(image_name, classifier):
    window_width, window_height = (64, 64)
    step_size = 64
    image = cv2.imread(image_name)
    image = np.array(image)
    temp = image
    image = image / 255.0

    for i in range(0, image.shape[1] - window_width, step_size):
        for j in range(0, image.shape[0] - window_height, step_size):
            window = image[i:i + window_width, j:j + window_height, :]
            print(window.shape)
```

But after 25 iterations, the window size shrinks to (55, 64, 3) and eventually to (0, 64, 3). What am I doing wrong?  The shape of the input image is (375, 1242, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Well that was a dumb mistake. As soon as i posted the question I realized I was reading the image in as Width x Height when I should've been reading it in as Height x Width. Changing

```
window = image[i:i + window_width, j:j + window_height, :]
```

to

```
window = image[j:j + window_height, i:i + window_width, :]
```

solved my problem.